# Kettle PDI how to pass multiple parameters not used in Table Input

Tags: kettle, pentaho-spoon

I'm converting data from one database to another with a slightly different structure. In my flow at some point I need to read data from the first database filtering on the id coming from previous steps.

This is the image of my flow:

[image]

In the step "ZtlBus note" the query is:

```
SELECT e.*,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(v.dataInserimento)*1000 as timestamp
FROM verbale_evento ve JOIN evento e ON ve.eventi_id=e.id
WHERE ve.Verbale_id=? AND e.titolo='Note verbale'
```

Because I've just one parameter, in the previous step I use a Select values step. Unfortunately, after the Table input I need others fields coming from previous steps (Audit step) as marked in the picture.

I'm wondering how I can pass these fields after Table input. Some advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use the "Database Join" step instead the input table step you will be able to keep the previous values of your transformation.